# seq_along() - truncating a replication in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to generate the month number to go along with a list of values. The problem is that the list is not a full 2 replications of 12 months. It is 12 from the first year and 10 from the second year.

```
tibble(value=rnorm(22))
```

Some things I have tried are `rep(1:12,2)`, thinking that the sequence would stop
when it hit the end of the length of the dataframe. I also tried `seq_along(along.with=value,1:12)` with the same line of thinking.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want the `length.out` argument to `rep()`:

```
rep(1:12, length.out = 22)
```

which gives

```
> rep(1:12, length.out = 22)
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

We get this because, from `?rep`:

```
 ‘length.out’ may be given in place of ‘times’, in which case ‘x’
 is repeated as many times as is necessary to create a vector of
 this length.  If both are given, ‘length.out’ takes priority and
 ‘times’ is ignored.
```

Answer (score 1):

I would roll out 22 months and then use a modulo operator to get months in subsequent year(s)

```
library(dplyr)
tibble(value=rnorm(22)) %>%
mutate(month=1:22,
       month=ifelse(month%%12==0, 12, month%%12)
```